# left div + right div + center div = 100% width. How to realise?

Tags: css, xhtml, layout, html

I have three divs and one main div:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="left" style="width:201px; float:left;">
     .... 
    </div>
    <div id="centre" style="float:left;">
     ....   
    </div>
    <div id="right" style="width:135px; float:right;">
     ....
    </div>
</div>
```

How it is possible to make **centre** div max width, so that 
containerDivWidth = leftDivWidth+ rightDivwidth + centreDivWidth;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you are trying to achieve is the "Holy Grail" layout.

There is a great List Apart article about this Layout, you should check it:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail

Answer (score 3):

This will allow for you to have fixed right and left columns and a flexible center portion:

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
  #left {
    float: left;
    width: 201px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  #centre {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }

  #right {
    float: right;
    width: 135px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;"> 
  <div id="left">Left</div>
  <div id="right">Right</div>
  <div id="centre">Middle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice Simple and fast to apply

Answer (score 0):

What I've previously done, is to set `centre` to have a left margin of 201px, and a right margin of 135px. Set it to relative positioning (instead of floating it), and then it should fill the entire remaining space in between the left and right columns.

I can't seem to find one of my old code examples, so this is the best I can do at the moment. Hope it helps!

Comment: This seems on track, but I can't see a way to get the right bit to "float" back up to be inline, as the width of the middle bit is too wide.

Comment: If you remove the float from the centre div, and set it to display:inline it should slot in between the two outside divs.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: 
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/holy-grail-no-quirks-mode.htm
[image]
<sub>(source: [matthewjamestaylor.com](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels-dimensions.gif))</sub>

Answer (score -1):

You cannot mix relative and fixed width which is in my opinion a shortcoming in CSS.

The best you can do is something like:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;"> 
    <div id="left" style="width:20%; float:left;"> 
     ....  
    </div> 
    <div id="centre" style="width:65%; float:left;"> 
     ....    
    </div> 
    <div id="right" style="width:15%; float:right;"> 
     .... 
    </div> 
</div>
```

I'll be very happy if I'm wrong.

Comment: Really right and left div's are not fixed(I've set their width just for example). They contain some content that set their width automatically. But the problem that the centre div should get all available surface between left and right.